# Windows option is not showing in the GRUB menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, boot-repair

Initially everything was working fine, but suddenly on clicking Windows in the grub menu this error starts showing:

````
```none
Setting partition type to 0x7
error: failure writing sector 0x0 to 'hd1'
```
````

(Note : hd0 is my hard drive which doesn't use AND hd1 is my SSD.)

So I ran `update-grub` on my Ubuntu machine and then the Windows option disappeared from the grub menu.

I tried:

1. I found that both Windows and Ubuntu are on legacy BIOS, so there is no compatibility issue.
2. Manually added these entries in /etc/grub.d/40_custom
   menuentry 'Windows 10' {
   search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 205C8FE55C8FB3D6
   chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
   }

   I also tried with address `/mnt/nvme0n1p1/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi` as I found bootmgfw.efi file on this address only, not on the above address.
3. Edited `/etc/default/grub` :

   ```
    GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
   ```
4. Ran `update-grub` then no Windows OS was detected. Here is the output:

   ```
   Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
   Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
   Generating grub configuration file ...
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic
   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-41-generic
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-38-generic
   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-38-generic
   Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-71-generic
   Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-71-generic
   Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
   Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
   Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
   Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
   done
   ```

   Similarly no output was produced for os-prober either.
5. After manually adding Windows, now grub is showing the Windows option,  but on clicking it produces this error:

   ```
   error: invalid signature
   Press any key to continue.
   ```
6. I also tried running Boot-Repair, but it also failed to locate windows. Here is the output: [OUTPUT LINK](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/f9z5GrvGPN/)

   https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/f9z5GrvGPN/

```
============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================

Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of
nvme0n1p5 into the MBR of nvme0n1.
Grub-efi would not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

The settings chosen by the user will reinstall the grub2 of
nvme0n1p5 into the MBR of nvme0n1.
Grub-efi will not be selected by default because no ESP detected.
The boot flag will be placed on nvme0n1p1.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s win-legacy-basic-fix


Quantity of real Windows: 1
WinSE in nvme0n1p1
/mnt/nvme0n1p1/ may need repair.
/mnt/nvme0n1p1/bootmgr may need repair.

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p5/etc/default/grub

======================= Reinstall the grub2 of nvme0n1p5 =======================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.06-2ubuntu7

==> Reinstall the GRUB of nvme0n1p5 into the MBR of nvme0n1

grub-install /dev/nvme0n1
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-41-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-71-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-71-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.

Unhide GRUB boot menu in nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg

Boot successfully repaired.

You can now reboot your computer.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1 and looks at sector 
    1 of the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and 
    looks for (,msdos5)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on nvme0n1p5
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on nvme0n1p1

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: UHD Graphics 620 GP108M [GeForce MX150] from Intel Corporation NVIDIA Corporation
BOOT_IMAGE of the installed session in use:
/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic root=UUID=1cdf9ad1-9af0-4dc9-b0b4-f2705ebe502f ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
df -Th / : /dev/nvme0n1p5 ext4   63G   53G  6.1G  90% /

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: V1.10(1.10) from Insyde Corp.
The firmware seems EFI-compatible, but this installed-session is in Legacy/BIOS/CSM mode (not in EFI mode).



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p5   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios
nvme0n1p1   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
nvme0n1p2   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p1   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p2   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p2   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x3bc18fd1
          Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
nvme0n1p1 *         2048 842551295 842549248 401.8G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
nvme0n1p2      842551296 843599871   1048576   512M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
nvme0n1p3      843603966 976771071 133167106  63.5G  5 Extended
nvme0n1p5      843603968 976771071 133167104  63.5G 83 Linux

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1:500GB:nvme:512:512:msdos:WDC WDS500G2B0C-00PXH0:;
1:1049kB:431GB:431GB:ntfs::boot;
2:431GB:432GB:537MB:ntfs::;
3:432GB:500GB:68.2GB:::;
5:432GB:500GB:68.2GB:ext4::;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL      PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                       
nvme0n1                                                                                                   
├─nvme0n1p1 ntfs     205C8FE55C8FB3D6                     3bc18fd1-01                                     
├─nvme0n1p2 ntfs     3A208E6B208E2E47                     3bc18fd1-02                          New Volume 
├─nvme0n1p3                                               3bc18fd1-03                                     
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4     1cdf9ad1-9af0-4dc9-b0b4-f2705ebe502f 3bc18fd1-05                                     

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                                     Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1                       51.2G  87% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p2                        502M   2% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p2
/dev/nvme0n1p5                          6G  85% /

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


=================== nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   1cdf9ad1-9af0-4dc9-b0b4-f2705ebe502f
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-41-generic   1cdf9ad1-9af0-4dc9-b0b4-f2705ebe502f
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-38-generic   1cdf9ad1-9af0-4dc9-b0b4-f2705ebe502f
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.15.0-71-generic   1cdf9ad1-9af0-4dc9-b0b4-f2705ebe502f
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
Windows 10
Windows 101

======================== nvme0n1p5/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=1cdf9ad1-9af0-4dc9-b0b4-f2705ebe502f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/nvme0n1p1 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

==================== nvme0n1p5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false
GRUB_DEFAULT="2"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=false

================= nvme0n1p5: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 408.578414917 = 438.707732480  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 460.581150055 = 494.545244160  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
 452.108428955 = 485.447729152  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 452.108428955 = 485.447729152  boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-71-generic                 1
 429.991817474 = 461.700198400  boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-38-generic                 2
 446.679325104 = 479.618273280  boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic                 2
 446.679325104 = 479.618273280  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 439.511135101 = 471.921487872  boot/initrd.img                                4
 439.511135101 = 471.921487872  boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-71-generic              4
 426.010238647 = 457.425010688  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-38-generic             99
 457.261714935 = 490.981027840  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-41-generic              5
 457.261714935 = 490.981027840  boot/initrd.img.old                            5

=================== nvme0n1p5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Apr 16  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Apr 16  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Apr 16  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13398 May 24 20:57 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Apr 16  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Feb 21  2022 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   511 May 26 20:02 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Apr 16  2022 41_custom
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root  4096 May 25 11:42 backup

======================== nvme0n1p5/etc/grub.d/40_custom ========================

#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 205C8FE55C8FB3D6
    chainloader (${root})/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
#menuentry 'Windows 101' {
#   search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 3A208E6B208E2E47
#   chainloader (${root})/Windows/Boot/EFI/bootmgfw.efi
#}
```

6. I also created a bootable pendrive to repair Windows as suggested in some posts, but that also is not able to find Windows.

Comment: Please reformat your question to make it readable. Nobody will spend time, if its not even worth to you placing a readable question.

Comment: Better just to leave link to Summary Report. Easier to read. You do have BIOS/MBR installs, but put an UEFI entry in 40_custom. Microsoft has required vendors to install in UEFI boot mode to gpt partitioned drives, so surprised you have BIOS. You have to make sure Windows fast start up & bitlocker are off. And grub only boots working Windows. When Windows turns fast startup back on, you have to temporally install Windows boot loader, fix Windows, & restore grub. Always have two flash drives, one Windows repair/recovery & one Ubuntu. If UEFI, you can always boot from UEFI boot menu.

Comment: @oldfred 
1) I installed windows using windows insider program only, and selected MBR partition, NTFS type.
2)From ubuntu i am not able to mount the partition in read-write partition, so don't know how to make sure Windows fast start up & bitlocker are off, could you please elaborate more on this.
3) I am not able to locate windows using update option(giving error nothing exists) only custom option is showing but i don't my data to get lost when using bootable pendrive.

Please let me know what can i do. Thanks

Comment: @Marco Sir,I have edited the question so please let me know the way around.

Comment: It not typical to use MBR in a dual boot configuration with Windows, but boot-repair did find both operating systems. The boot-repair utility has to be run from a live session, so make sure you're not running it on your installed system. As far as disabling fast startup in Windows, this is essential when dual booting. If you're using bitlocker in Windows, you should also suspend its encryption when making these kinds of changes/repairs. You'll need to consult Windows support/documentation for more specific details about those Windows features and how to manage them

Comment: Someone has posted that Windows 11 is UEFI/gpt only. If you recently installed Windows better to convert now, before it has lots of data & settings. But conversion from MBR to gpt will totally erase entire drive. How you boot install media BIOS or UEFI is how it installs. New systems since about 2020 with some vendors are UEFI only. If you keep BIOS, you have to regularly reinstall boot loaders. Windows boot to fix Windows, grub boot to multiple boot.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i connected a new SSD to my laptop and copied all tha data to it.

Then installed new windows.